# How to udpate an array of values for the shadermaterial in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm using Three.js to render dynamic shadows. In my GLSL shader, I have a uniform vec3[] parameter and a uniform float[] parameter. During the rendering process, I want update these uniform values. My question is how to update them in my animate function.

My code looks likes:

```
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        uniform vec3 pos[4];
        uniform float size[4];
        uniform float tt;

        void main() {
            vec3 color = vec3(0.0)
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
             color += myfunction(pos[i], size[i]); // the final color value is within [0,1]
            }
            gl_FragColor=vec4(color * tt,1.0);
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var mypos = new Array();
        var mysize = new Array();
        var renderer, camera, scene, mesh, material;

        init();
        animate();
 
        function init(){         
    
        // initiate renderer, scene, camera, mesh
        ...
        //

        mypos[0] = new vec3(1,0,0);
        mypos[1] = new vec3(0,1,0);
        mypos[2] = new vec3(0,0,1);
        mypos[3] = new vec3(1,1,0);

        mysize[0] = 0.1;
        mysize[1] = 0.2;        
        mysize[2] = 0.3;
        mysize[3] = 0.4;

       material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
          uniforms: {
            pos: { value: [mypos[0], mypos[1], mypos[2], mypos[3]] },
            size: { value: [mysize[0], mysize[1], mysize[2], mysize[3]] },
            tt : {value: 0.3}
          },
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
        });
        } 
       
        ...
        }

        function animate()
        { 
          for(var i=0; i<4)
          {
            mypos[i] = new vec3(mypos[i].x + 0.1*i, mypos[i].y + 0.2*i, mypos[i].z + 0.3*i);
            mysize[i] = mysize[i]+ 0.5* i;
          }
          tt = tt + 0.01;
          
          // To change tt 
          material.uniforms.tt.value = tt;
          
          //How to update mypos[4] and mysize[4] for material
          ??
        }
         
    </script>
```

I know that I can use **material.uniforms.tt.value = tt;**  to update the value of tt in the shader, But when I update the values of the two arrays, mypos[4] and mysize[4], I tried to use the following code:

```
material.uniforms.pos.value = [mypos[0], mypos[1], mypos[2], mypos[3]];
material.uniforms.size.value = [mysize[0], mysize[1], mysize[2], mysize[3]];
```

But it gives the error that **Uncaught TypeError: firstElem.toArray is not a function**.

So I want to know how to update the values of mypos[4] and mysize[4] for the material.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The type of the `pos` value needs to be `THREE.Vector3[]`

Comment: Do you mean `mypos[0] = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);` ? I have modified my code in this way. However, when I use `material.uniforms.pos.value = [mypos[0], mypos[1], mypos[2], mypos[3]];` to update the values for the shader, it still gives me the error that **firstElem.toArray is not a function**.

Comment: Please include the whole error, including the call stack. If it looks like gibberish, switch from `three.min.js` to `three.js` and run it again. It should tell you exactly where and when the error is occurring, and then we can look at why that might happen.

Comment: I solved this problem. I update 'uniform vec3 pos[4]' and 'uniform float size[4]' using  the code: `for (var i=0; i<4; i++){ material.uniforms.pos.value[i].set(mypos[i].x, mypos[i].y, mypos[i].z); material.uniforms.size.value[i]=mysize[i]; } `.  Now it works fine.  This is the link https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-udpate-an-array-of-values-for-the-shadermaterial-in-three-js/48050 where I get the solution.